# currency converter help c#

Tags: c#, currency

im just a beginner to this and im making a currency converter where a whole number is entered and validated and an exchange rate is entered and validated. im having problems on how to then calculate the exchange rate from the two validated values entered previously. here is the code i have done so far also this is a console application.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        wholeNumber();
        exhangeNumber();


    }

    private static void exhangeNumber()
    {
        double evalue;
        bool valid;

        Console.WriteLine("please enter an exchange rate");

        do
        {
            try
            {
                evalue = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("the exchange rate entered is: {0:F2}", evalue);
                valid = true;
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("invalid Exchange rate please try again");
                valid = false;
            }
        }
        while (valid == false);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }





    private static void wholeNumber()
    {
        int ivalue;
        bool valid;


        Console.WriteLine("please enter a whole number");
        do
        {
            try
            {
                ivalue = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("the valuse you have entered is : {0:F0}", ivalue);
                valid = true;
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("this is not a whole number please try again");
                valid = false;
            }


        } while (valid == false);

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never return the values back to your main program

```
private static double exhangeNumber()
private static double wholeNumber()
```

At the bottom of these instead of using console readline use, `return ivalue/evalue;` respectively. Then in main you can do

```
Console.WriteLine(exchangeNumber() * wholeNumber());
Console.ReadLine();
```

---

As Steve said in the comments, you may wish to use `TryParse` instead of `Parse` to get the values as it will give you extra error handling and will give the default value if your user's input isn't a valid number, for a double this is `0.0`.. As well as this, TryParse will also return a boolean as to whether or not the parsing was successful

For example:

```
 evalue = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
   is the same as (but improved)
 double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out evalue);
```

even better

```
 while(!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out evalue);
{
    Console.WriteLine("this is not a whole number please try again");
} 
Console.WriteLine("the valuse you have entered is : {0:F0}", evalue);
```

Comment: @Steve - Sure I was saving that for a couple years down the line when OP looks back on their code to improve it :)

Comment: @Steve - If it can be improved any more feel free to let me know, thanks

Comment: when i use return with evalue and ivalue it gives me a "use of unassigned local vairable 'evalue'" error

Comment: @MrCode - Where abouts? in that case you need to assign them ... `double evalue = 0.0`, didn't see that one coming

Comment: Yes, I was thinking to TryParse  because it removes the need of an Exception handler to drive the program flow. As written by the OP the code needs the try/catch to reenter the input loop and this is (usually) a bad practice.

Comment: when i do this it runs and takes the error off but now just seems to loop by it and wont calculate. sorry for hassle =/

Comment: @Steve - Yes but this seems definately like homework and wasn't sure what needed to be included :) thanks again

Comment: @MrCode - Could you update your question with the new code? (keep old code there to preserve your question)

Comment: oh wait forget that ive done something wrong got it working now thanks for all your help guys !